# assign span class information to local variable using Selenium Webdriver in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, google-chrome, selenium

I want to pull information from a website, and assign it to a local variable in my program.

The HTML on the website looks like this:

```
<span class="button pagenum"><span class="range"><span class="rangeFrom">1</span> to <span class="rangeTo">100</span></span> of <span style="border: 2px solid red;" class="totalcount">2500</span></span>
```

[It looks like this on the website.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wcIYO.png) 
I am using Selenium Webdriver, C# in Visual Studio, and Google Chrome.

I really don't even know where to begin, as this is among my first selenium projects.

Any/all help is appreciated!

Comment: Do you want separate text in separate variable or wholr text in single variable??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to assign whole text into Single variable just try as below :

```
string variable = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("span.button.pagenum")).Text;
```

Or if you want to assign all values into individual variables try as below :

```
string rangeFrom = driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("rangeFrom")).Text;

string rangeTo = driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("rangeTo")).Text;

string totalcount = driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("totalcount")).Text;
```

Hope it helps..:)